# Method to find an analytical or semi-analytical solution for this diferential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$a(η)[S/η^2 +Fη^2+Gη^4+Hη^6+J]+a'(η) [K/η+ηZ+η^3 C]+a''(η) [η^2 L+P]=0$

where S,F,G,H,J,K,Z,C,L and P are constants
and a(η) is the function that's being sought.

This equation comes from the eigenvalue problem of the  graphene nano-ring with spin-orbit interaction and magnectic field using the mexican-hat potential. To solve this equation I tried the Froebenius method (it didn't work), and the Maple software (it didn't work either). The group has found a numerical solution using the Runge-Kunta method, but it's necessary to have an analytical or semi-analytical solution to comprehend the real influence of spin-orbit interaction in graphene.

I would like to add that this is not homework. In fact, this is an ongoing work with my adviser and after more than one month trying to obtain this solution I decided that I should ask for some help. I appreciate any reference or some hint that could help me with solving this problem.

Comment: Do you have any reasons to believe an analytical solution exists? General homogeneous second-order ODEs typically do not have one, and I don't expect one here unless the coefficients satisfy some special relationships. The ODE can be easily solved numerically, of course.

Comment: Sounds like this would perhaps be better as a MathOverflow question.  (Please make sure if you crosspost to there you include the link to this post there and vice versa.)

Comment: may be you should change type of potential to get simpler equation. Also one should take into account order of constants. May be you can neglect some of them

Comment: If you multiply through by another $\eta^2$ it looks almost sensible, even exponents from 0 to 8 for $a,$ odd from 1 to 5 for $a',$ then again even from 2 to 4 for $a''.$ I would say it depends quite a bit on the $\pm$ signs for the coefficients and the relative sizes, finally how close $\eta$ gets to 0.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much chance of a closed-form solution in general.  But you can get series solutions by Frobenius's method, since $\eta=0$ is a regular singular point.  The indicial equation is $r^2 + \dfrac{K-P}{P} r + \dfrac{S}{P} = 0$.

If $H=0$ Maple does come up with rather complicated closed-form solutions involving the HeunC function.  Based on this, for $H \ne 0$ you might be able to get solutions as series in powers of $H$.

Comment: Thanks Mr Robert Israel, I aplied the Froebenius method again and find the equation's solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlexandreCavalheiroDias: If you found the solution, why don't you write it as an answer, so that other people can benefit from it in the future?

Comment: @user1271772 Do you realize that this question and answer was from December 2012?  It's unlikely the OP will see your comment.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, the OP is a friend of my friend, and we have been working together on trying to launch the [Materials Modeling Stack Exchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=OWQ1ZTEwNzhmOGY2MGIxYWNkNTU5MWE5ZjhiODc2YjVjZjUzMjJjODQ4MWQyMWQ5MzNkYzE1ZDMxMTUxZThmNFkXYBO-Vm8c7Eyys9QqLd_yU5Q_b372ma-7azTIB9bM0), which I believe might also interest you, since most of the "example questions" have been mathematics related, but with a focus on the quantum mechanics of chemical bonding and materials geometry/design.